# why Observable snapshot observer vector

Tags: java

In Observable's notifyObservers method, why does the coder use  `arrLocal = obs.toArray();`?
Why does not coder iterate vector directly? Thanks

```
public void notifyObservers(Object arg) {

    Object[] arrLocal;

    synchronized (this) {
        /* We don't want the Observer doing callbacks into
        * arbitrary code while holding its own Monitor.
        * The code where we extract each Observable from 
        * the Vector and store the state of the Observer
        * needs synchronization, but notifying observers
        * does not (should not).  The worst result of any 
        * potential race-condition here is that:
        * 1) a newly-added Observer will miss a
        *   notification in progress
        * 2) a recently unregistered Observer will be
        *   wrongly notified when it doesn't care
        */
        if (!changed)
            return;
        arrLocal = obs.toArray();
        clearChanged();
    }

    for (int i = arrLocal.length-1; i>=0; i--)
        ((Observer)arrLocal[i]).update(this, arg);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

They want to avoid concurrent modifications, but at the same time not stay in a synchronized block for too long (especially when they don't know what code they are actually calling into).

Option one would be to synchronize for the whole operation, and iterate over the vector directly while notifying the observers. As the comment points out ("We don't want the Observer doing callbacks into arbitrary code while holding its own Monitor"), this would keep the Observable locked for potentially a long time.

Option two is to synchronize only long enough to get a consistent copy of the vector.
They can then release the lock before iterating over their private copy.

**Update:** If the Observer updated the list of Observers, iterating over it concurrently might not be a good idea anyway. So a copy seems advised even in a single thread scenario.

Comment: Worse, option one will create a deadlock if the Observer attempted to add another listener (or remove itself as a listener) in it's callback.

Comment: I think a thread cannot deadlock itself (the Observers are called on the same thread). Of course, if more threads get involved somehow, then yes, that could happen.

Comment: Option one could result in a ConcurrentModificationException though, "if the Observer attempted to add another listener". So a copy is advised anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers in this thread are correct about the purpose of the copy. I will say, though, that Java 5+ already has the right data structure that will do that copying automatically: [`java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html).

Comment: Except that CopyOnWriteArrayList is quite heavy for frequent updates. I suppose one adds observers not very often, so that may not matter.

Comment: @Thilo: Indeed, a listener list is the usual use case for `CopyOnWriteArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

The coder is using the "obs.toArray()" to "snapshot" the current observers. They are trying to prevent iterating over a vector that may change underneath them, without explicitly synchronizing around the Vector.

Answer (score 0):

That code implements the semantic that `notifyObservers` should notify exactly those observers registered at the time of the call (or at least at the time of the copy).

If this semantic weren't needed, then the author could have simply iterated over the observers calling update, as you suggest, as long as the iteration were thread safe. In fact, that is how I would have written it.

Regarding how this class is written, it is broken to me. Seemingly, the notifier is asked to write code like this:

```
observable.setChanged();
observable.notifyObservers(obj1);
```

That is, the notifier first marks the observable as changed or else `notifyObservers` does nothing. Also note that the call to `notifyObservers` calls `clearChanged` as part of its operation.

So consider the case that two threads are doing notifications. These two commands could be interleaved across the threads like so:

```
Thread 1: observable.setChanged();
Thread 2: observable.setChanged();
Thread 1: observable.notifyObservers(obj1);
Thread 2: observable.notifyObservers(obj2);
```

In this case, the first call to `notifyObservers` by thread 1 works as expected. But the second call to `notifyObservers` by thread 2 does nothing because the changed flag was cleared by the first call. So the observers never see the `obj2` argument.

The only solution I can see to avoid this is to synchronize the calls to `setChanged` and `notifyObservers` so that they don't get interleaved. That of course means that the observers get notified inside of a synchronization block which violates the author's statement that that should not happen. Because of this, it's hard to recommend using this class.